# copy data from one table to another using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to copy data to `A_Table` data from `B_Table`

So I followed following [ASP.NET  forum post's answer](http://forums.asp.net/t/1322979.aspx?Copy%20values%20from%20one%20table%20to%20another%20table%20using%20LINQ%20to%20SQL%20)

I just configured that answer according my approach, so this is linq query to copy those data

```
    public ActionResult Copy_Data()
    {
        var str = from a in db.B_Table select a;

        foreach (var val in str)
        {
            A_TableModelClass ls = new A_TableModelClass();

            ls.Product_ID = val.Product_ID;
            ls.ProductName = val.ProductName;
            ls.CreatedDate = val.CreatedDate;

            db.A_Table.Insert(ls);
        }

        db.SubmitChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller");
    }
```

but here I'm getting 2 errors in following location

Error 1

1. `db.A_Table.Insert(ls);`

> DbSet' does not contain a definition for 'Insert' and no
>   extension method 'Insert' accepting a first argument of type
>   'DbSet'

Error 2

2. `db.SubmitChanges();`

> 'ProjectEntities' does not contain a definition for 'SubmitChanges'
>   and no extension method 'SubmitChanges' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'ProjectEntities'

Actually I imported `Using System.Linq`

Comment: I think you're looking for .Add() not .Insert()

Comment: @aloneguid and whats the replacement for `SubmitChanges` ?

Comment: If you're working with a data layer you should *at least* know what it is. This is Entity Framework, not Lint-to-Sql.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate. OP very clearly wants to copy a row from one table to another. The "Insert a copy of existing row using Linq to Entities" OP wants to copy a row into the SAME TABLE. The difference in operations to make this happen may be very slight (if different at all), but I still, personally, don't see these as duplicate questions. (Just my $0.02)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `db.A_Table.Add(ls);` and then `db.SaveChanges()`